# Android Layout_Weight for Fixed Width Not Working

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to use layout_weight and layout_width with a linear layout with horizontal orientation.  The linear layout contains 1 TextView and 2 RadioButtons (in a RadioButtonGroup). I'd like the TextView to fill up the space to the left of the RadioButtons and always keep the RadioButtons right-justified on the screen.  So regardless of the amount of text, the TextView should take up the space so that the RadioButtons are always right-justified. The LinearLayout is used in a ListView to have multiple rows in the list.

Unfortunately, the TextView is wrapping content despite specifying android:layout_width="0dp" and android:weight="1". And the RadioButtons are not lined up on the right nicely.
Here's the image

[image: ](http://postimg.org/image/549k28f4t/)]

Here's the XML for the LinearLayout.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:orientation="horizontal"
   android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="false" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/jokeTextView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"/>

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/ratingRadioGroup"
        android:layout_width="35dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/likeButton"
            android:layout_width="35dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:button="@drawable/like" 
            android:gravity="right"/>

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/dislikeButton"
            android:layout_width="35dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:button="@drawable/dislike" 
            android:gravity="right"/>

    </RadioGroup>

</LinearLayout>
```

I also tried it with setting RadioButton android:layout_width="wrap_content" which did not work either.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try `android:gravity="fill_horizonal"` in the `LinearLayout`.  I think the issue is that the `LinearLayout` is shrinking itself to smallest possible dimension inside the outer container.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this..

I guess your **listview** width as `wrap_content` change it as `match_parent` and try

```
<ListView 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Issue is with your listview. There is no issue with the item layout

Change your listview

```
 android:layout_width="match_parent""
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a layout on one side and one on the other, use RelativeLayout: alignParentRight/Left.